# How to design RESTful API endpoint to get by different fields with different data types

Tags: rest

I am wondering what is the best way of design RESTful API endpoint for searching by different fields.

For example I have a resource as

```
class Employee 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MobilePhoneNumber {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Now I would like to design a GET endpoint to search an employee by different fields. If frontend passes an id to the endpoint, then I search by Id.

How to design the endpoint to fulfill this requirement. Or shall I create three endpoints for each field?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create three endpoints. Just have a `GET` search endpoint returning multiple employees:

```
GET /api/employees
```

Then allow for the search parameters to be passed via the querystring. e.g

```
GET /api/employees?name=Ben&Email=ben@stackoverflow.com
```

For the ID you would normally expose another `GET` endpoint to get just the one employee with that ID rather than allowing a search for multiple employees with the ID:

```
GET /api/employees/{Id}
```

Comment: Aha...interesting. Then how can I distinguish list all and search by field endpoints? Seems like people usually use GET /api/employees to list employees. Will API be confused?

Comment: No I would go with including the ID via the route as per my final comment. i.e. GET /api/employees/{Id} (returning one employee) rather than via the querystring (returning multiple).

Comment: @Ben `GET /api/employees` means get all, not confusing at all

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest two `GET` endpoints. The first return one single object and the last one return an array.

For find the resource by ID, I could suggest an endpoint to accept the id as a **mandatory** information, like:

```
GET /api/employees/123
```

Because you can return just one single resource from the ID information. If the ID does not exist, you can return a `404` (*Not Found*) HTTP code.

Response:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Lock",
    "mobilePhoneNumber": "13334564454",
    "email": "john.lock@dmail.com"
}
```

For the other fields, you create another endpoint to return an array of resources passing the fields as **optional** parameters:

```
GET /api/employees?name=John&mobilePhoneNumber=333&email=dmail.com
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "John Lock",
        "mobilePhoneNumber": "13334564454",
        "email": "john.lock@dmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 321,
        "name": "John Smith",
        "mobilePhoneNumber": "33367546566",
        "email": "john.smith@dmail.com"
    }

]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Since @strickt01 answered earlier, I accept his answer.

Comment: Even though the accepted answer is correct (and was posted first), this answer is much more detailed. +1