# how to design a fastapi endpoint for different GET actions on same resource

Tags: rest, fastapi

I want to design a single fastapi endpoint that accepts different input parameters from clients and performs different GET operations accordingly on the same resource.

My initial thought is, I could accept something like an "expected_action" parameter from the client along with the input parameters and perform the corresponding action, but then I am not sure how it will affect the pydantic field validations, as some input parameters may be missing for certain "expected_action"s.

I have seen similar threads here (a closer one was this - [https://stackoverflow.com/q/59563441/7474253](https://stackoverflow.com)), but they are not helping or are related to other frameworks like Spring. What I am interested in is, the best practice for fastapi framework.  The fastapi documentation talks about mixing up path, query and body parameters, but is that what should be applied here ? Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What is this action that the endpoint is supposed to accept?

Comment: If the endpoint expects different types of bodies, you can create a `Union` between the allowed values, but generally it might be better to have different endpoints if these operations are very different (also, a GET operation _should_ be idempotent, so it shouldn't change the data in any way).

Comment: I have "subscriptions" as the resource and I want to have a single "/subscriptions" end point that can accept 3 types of GET requests - (1) get all subscriptions of all users when there is no parameter passed (2) get all subscriptions of the user when the user parameter is passed (3) get the latest subscription of user when the user parameter is passed.    Again, in 1, I just need the subscription ID where as in 2 and 3, I need many more details.